# Intellij Not Recognizing Ruby Sources for Rails Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, intellij-idea

I'm trying to add an existing Ruby on Rails application as an Intellij (Ultimate) project. I'm following the [instructions provided by JetBrains](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/RUBYDEV/Opening+Rails+projects+in+IntelliJ+IDEA). After clicking "Import Project" and "Create project from existing sources", Intellij searches for sources and locates every Java file in my application/vendor/bundle/ruby/[version]/gem/[gemname] directories. It does not recognize my top-level application directory as a "Ruby" source directory.

I have the Ruby Plugin installed (Version: 2017.3.2017122) and my project default SDK is ruby-2.4.3-p205. The application I'm trying to import uses Rails 5.1.5. Why won't Intellij recognize Ruby?

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that I needed to clean the old gems out of my vendor/ folder. After doing that, Intellij successfully picked up my application root directory.